# SFspeechRecognizer recognize speech more than one minutes in ios 15?

Tags: ios, sfspeechrecognizer

I'm beginner swift programmer.

Ios 15 can transcribe speech more than 1 minute.

Can SfSpeechRecognizer transcribe speech more than 1 minute?

Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: did you find the answer to this @kabakaba?

Comment: In iOS 15, SfSpeechRecognizer transcribe speech more than 1 minute. Under iOS 14, SfSpeechRecognizer is limited withen 1 minute.

Comment: Hmm, I tried to iPhone 7 15.5, but it's still limited. Note that it only happened when using `SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest`, and not with `SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest `